# Drop down values disappearing if i click submit button more than one time

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a php page with 2 drop down boxes, submit and cancel button.

If I select values in both drop down boxes and press submit button, it will redirect to the same page and it will display the selected values. Now the problem is, if I click on submit button one more time (without selecting drop down boxes), the selected values will disappear from drop-down boxes (drop down boxes will be empty).

Could anyone please help me to, retain the values in drop-down boxes if I click submit button more than one times?

Thanks in advance.

Br,
Mahadev

Comment: You need to post your code, how else can we tell what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @hakre I did close-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented your problem to a file.
This file displays only one drop down box and a submit button. This is only some parts of your file. You can modify my code below for another drop down box and other elements.

Here's the code (Quite long):

```
...
<form action="" method="post">
<select name='option'>
<?php
if($_POST["option"]=="Option 1")
{
echo "<option></option>
<option selected>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>";
}
else if($_POST["option"]=="Option 2")
{
echo "<option></option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option selected>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>";
}
else if($_POST["option"]=="Option 3")
{
echo "<option></option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option selected>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>";
}
else if($_POST["option"]=="Option 4")
{
echo "<option></option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option selected>Option 4</option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option selected></option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
...
```

When you click the submit button, the value from the drop down is sent and it retrieves when the page loads again.
I use `post` method to send data and pass it to another page. (In this demo, I use the same page)
The `selected` attribute of the option tag makes that value to be selected as the page loads.

You may read this article from w3schools.
[Keep Values in Form.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)